# Ag-grid Row selection after user confirmation

Tags: ag-grid

I have a grid with master data and below it I have a form with details of the selected row. The user can update data of the details and save the changes. The grid (master data) is readonly.

And here the question:
If the user clicks another row and he has done changes in the details, I want to ask the user, if he wants to save the changes. When the user answer the question than NOW I want to select the row (Yes, No) or discard the selection.

I guess I have to use the property `suppressRowClickSelection=true`. Have you idea if it can works and if it is possible to achieve that with `ag-grid`?

Comment: What is the action if user clicks Yes? Which row should be selected?

Comment: The action if user clicks Yes is saving the edited details in the formular reload the data from backend and selecting the new row in grid. I have solved the problem with `suppressRowClickSelection=true` and defining a handler for `onCellClicked` like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264888/ag-grid-suppress-row-selection-inside-a-particular-column-cell